# WinForm Controls in context menu

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

I need to add some controls to context menu. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `ToolStripControlHost` to host your control in a context menu (or toolbar as well I think).

Here is an article briefly explaining how:
http://www.dotneat.net/2009/01/19/AddingYourOwnCustomControlToAWindowsFormsContextMenuUsingToolStripCustomHostClass.aspx

Comment: Great! I didn't thought that it would be so simple!